# ValueError: Error when checking : expected flatten_1_input to have shape (None, 4, 4, 512) but got array with shape (1, 150, 150, 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I followed the guide at [this link](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) to build a model and stopped before the finetuning part to test the model on some other images using the following code:

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
batch_size = 1

test_model = load_model('dog_cat_model.h5')

validation_data_dir = "test1"

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode='binary')

predictions = test_model.predict_generator(validation_generator, len(validation_generator.filenames));

for i in range(len(validation_generator.filenames)):
    print(validation_generator.filenames[i], ": ", predictions[i])
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected flatten_1_input to have shape (None, 4, 4, 512) but got array with shape (1, 150, 150, 3)
```

printing test_model.summary gives the following output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               2097408
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257
=================================================================
Total params: 2,097,665
Trainable params: 2,097,665
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

And I am clueless how to figure out what this means.

Here is the code I used for creating the model:

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
batch_size = 16
train_samples = 2000
validation_samples = 800
epochs = 50


def save_bottlebeck_features():
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

    # build the VGG16 network
    model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)

    validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)

    predict_size_train = int(math.ceil(train_samples / batch_size))

    bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(train_generator, predict_size_train)
    np.save('bottleneck_features_train.npy', bottleneck_features_train)

    predict_size_validation = int(math.ceil(validation_samples / batch_size))

    bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, predict_size_validation)
    np.save('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', bottleneck_features_validation)


def train_top_model():
    train_data = np.load('bottleneck_features_train.npy')
    train_labels = np.array([0] * (train_samples // 2) + [1] * (train_samples // 2))

    validation_data = np.load('bottleneck_features_validation.npy')
    validation_labels = np.array([0] * (validation_samples // 2) + [1] * (validation_samples // 2))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
              epochs=epochs,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))

    model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
    model.save('dog_cat_model.h5')


save_bottlebeck_features()
train_top_model()
```

I hope someone can help me out :)

Comment: Could you print out `validation_data.shape` from bottleneck training?

Comment: Sure, it prints this: (800, 4, 4, 512)

Comment: Ok. Now - could you print out `test_model.summary()`?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it properly in a comment :) - I'll throw it in the original post.

Comment: So this is the reason why - in line `predictions = test_model.predict_generator(validation_generator, len(validation_generator.filenames))` you are feeding an image to a `bottleneck` model.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot :) I guess I will have to do some more reading to properly understand what is really going on. I don't fully understand what a bottleneck model is, but I thought I had a model at this stage that I could use.

Comment: I formulated an answer :)

Comment: @M.Kahlen dId you managed to solve the error? I am getting a similar error; please share your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed bootleneck and image model logic in this line:

```
test_model.predict_generator(...)
```

Where you fed images to bottleneck model. This caused a shape error.

Comment: can you please elaborate your solution?

Answer (score 1):

try by replacing Flatten layer by GlobalAveragePooling2D or GlobalMaxPooling2D

Comment: Something like this? It says the first layer in a sequenced model must have input_shape, but I don't understand the parameters it takes: `model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format=None, input_shape=(batch_size, ?, ?, ?)))`

Comment: replace model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:])) with model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))

Comment: I get a similar error: `ValueError: Error when checking : expected global_average_pooling2d_1_input to have shape (None, 4, 4, 512) but got array with shape (1, 150, 150, 3)`

Comment: change model.fit(train_data, train_labels,   epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))    with model.fit(bottleneck_features_train, train_labels,epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(bottleneck_features_validation, validation_labels))

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
data_format='channels_last'
```

in `model.add()`

will work if backend is using Tensorflow, and

```
data_format='channels_first'
```

if backend is using theano.